# Updating table after deleting an item: MGSwipeTableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on project in Xcode 7 with Swift 7 and using MGSwipeTableCell.

When a user swipes left/right on a table cell I would like that cell to be deleted from the view but not from my backend database, and animate out left/right based on the direction of the swipe. When I run the app and test the function it sends back this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of 
sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) 
must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the 
update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or 
deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

Here is my code for the function:

```
cell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Skip!", backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1.0), callback: {
            (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
            print("Convenience callback for Skip button!")
            
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath!.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
            
            return true
        })]
        
        cell.rightExpansion.buttonIndex = 0
        
        cell.leftButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Apply!", icon: UIImage(named:"check.png"), backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1.0), callback: {
            (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
            print("Convenience callback for Apply button!")
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath!.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Right)
            
            return true
        })]
        
        cell.leftExpansion.buttonIndex = 0
        
        return cell
```

And here is my numberOfRowsInSection piece that I believe is causing the issue:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    
    return posts.count
        

}
```

Am I correct in thinking that the section above needs to be edited in order for this to work? I have tried a few different ways to fix this problem but haven't had much luck. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thank you in advance!

## Thanks to comments below I was able to figure it out

```
            self.posts.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Right)
```

Comment: The issue in the error is the *number of sections*, not the *number of rows in a given section*. This is because you are calling `deleteSections` to delete an entire section. (The default implementation of the `numberOfSections` method returns 1, so you need to override this to return zero if a section has been deleted.)

Comment: Would this be an additoinal override function I need to add to the VC then?

Comment: Yes, if you intended to delete a whole section instead of just one row.

Comment: Hmm, I do just want to delete one row. Would that be 'deleteRowsAtIndexPath'?

Comment: I replaced the delete line with `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)` but am still getting a similar error except now it is for the rows

Comment: That's great! Now make sure you are removing the post from `posts` right before you call the delete rows method.

Comment: YES! Thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `deleteSections…` with `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)`. Directly before that line, remove the post from `posts`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out from the comments above but this is the correct answer.